# JavaScript this inside function object

Tags: javascript

In a regular object, `this` inside a method is pointing to the object itself; in a function call, this is pointing to the caller, sometimes, the `Window` object if it is called globally. I have no problem with those.  What I don't understand is the code snippet below:

```
function test(){
  function method(){console.log(this);}
  method();
}
test()
```

Since JavaScript function is also an object, I would expect `this` inside `method` function should point to the caller which is `test` object.  However, it is pointed to `Window` object.  Why is that?  Can someone help me get a consistent understanding about this magic word `this`?  Thank you!

Comment: Here is a useful rule of thumb: if you have `foo.bar()` then `this === foo`. It's equal to the thing *before* the last dot. So `foo.bar.baz.quux()` will leave you with `this = foo.bar.baz`. If there is nothing before the dot, then you run into "special rules" where `this === undefined` or `this === window` depending on whether you're in strict mode or not.

Comment: it's all about JS closures, in your test function, after declaring method(), add `method = method.bind(this)` and 'this' will always point to the test scope function